# How to achieve filtered data on the selectbox based on the previous selectbox?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

How to achieve filtered data on the selectbox based on the previous selectbox

This is my JSON data

```
$scope.data=
[
     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "George Child1"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild1"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "Sally Child1"          
     },

     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "subCatName": "GeorgChild2"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "subCatName": "FollyChild2"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "subCatName": "FollyChild3"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "subCatName": "Infant Food"          
     }

]
```

This is my JSON data.

I have two selectboxes 
First Select Box for displaying parentName
Second Select Box for displaying childName

Initially first select box showing in ---select---- at that time second select box is disabled

When I select on the parentName of first select box I need to display the childNames of that parent only in second select box

This is my view page struture I need to aligned it in horzontal way

```
  <div class="col-md-3"> 
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Parent</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="data">
          <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in data | orderBy:'parentName'| groupBy:'parent'">{{key}}</option>           
        </select>
      </div>              
    </form>  
  </div>      
  <div class="col-md-3">      
    <form>    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Child Names</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="childnames">
          <option>--Select--</option>             
        </select>
      </div>          
    </form>     
</div>
```

Any remodification needed. Please help me

I am new in AngularJS any filter for any other method for getting this way.Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vzI4iodRxSj2r80l6HyD?p=preview).

In second select

```
<select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-model="vm.child"
    ng-options="data.childName for data in vm.data| filter: {parentName:vm.selectedParent}">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all Thankyou...Working fine but the problem is it cannot display ----Select---- in both Parent and Child.
One more thing if Parent is displayed select the child need to become disabled

Comment: I added

<select ng-model="vm.selectedParent" class="form-control" id="vm.data"
"ng-options="data.parentName for data in vm.data| orderBy:'parentName'| groupBy:'parentName'">   
<option>--Select--</option>     
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-model="vm.child"
ng-options="data.childName for data in vm.data| filter: {parentName:vm.selectedParent}">
<option>--Select--</option>
</select>
But its not working in group by

Comment: Working fine thankyou for your time.But one isssue when I click ----Select---- in Parent select box after selecting the child selectbox
The child select box will disable but it will not reagain ----Select--- in child box automatically. Actuallay my need is when i select ---Select-- in
parent selectbox the child box should be disable and showing ---Select---.  Ok Thankyou If you have any idea you just share me..

Comment: One more thing I need one more filter added in child options is it possible 
eg:removeWith:{childName : 'others'} when i added it but its not working only one filter is working in ng-option why? Is it any regulation for using that...

ng-options="data.childName for data in vm.data| filter: {parentName:vm.selectedParent} | removeWith:{childName : 'others'}">

Comment: I updated the plnkr. About `removeWith`, i try it : `| removeWith:{childName : 'Infant Food'}` and it's working fine. For the case that when you change in parent, you should change the vm.child property to `undefined` for the **view** to set it to **---Select---**

Comment: Thankou for everything...your code is working fine.But removeWith is not worked to me. I dont know, ok fine.
I need one guide from your side.
Actually in the above code I place that in one state ui-veiw. Only that selectbox Parent and ChildNames
When i select both, the details of that child will displayed inside the nested state of that selectbox ui-view ok....but different controllers im used  Understood!

Comment: Continued........I am using ng-change="getValue()" in childname selectbox .When i change childname it will alert in getValue() but inside that function i call that nested state ie $state.go(''childdetails); if bot are selcting it work fine but when i chnage childname alone it wont work Why? ng-change alerted but $state.go(''childdetails); is not working .But again when i change bot parent and childname it works..After selcting Parent if i need to change that child name $state.go doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-options="n.subCatName as    n.subCatName for n in data | filter:{parentName:parentSelect}" >
    <option>--Select--</option>             
</select>
```

Add ng-model="ng-model="parentSelect" in parent and then replace child select box with this code

Answer (score 0):

The following changes worked for me:-

1. Add a model to parent select element.`<select class="form-control" id="data" ng-model="parent">`
2. Use this model to filter childNames 
   `<select class="form-control" id="childnames"><option ng-repeat="value in data | filter: parent">{{value.childName}}</option></select>`